# Misplaced InstancedMeshes in THREE JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im trying to create terrain generation code where water generates on a certain Y level and stone on another. This is just a sandbox model im going to use later in my project of minecraft terrain generation. However, in the code 2 meshes arent placed and im wondering if there is something im missing?

[image]

CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>My first three.js app</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
  import * as THREE from 'https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
scene.background = new THREE.Color("lightblue");

const range = 4; // WIDTH AND LENGTH OF AREA


// MESSY ARRAYS THAT IM GOING TO FIX LATER
const textures = [
  new THREE.TextureLoader().load('StoneBlock.jpg'),
  new THREE.TextureLoader().load('water.jpg')
];

const materials = [
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: textures[0] }),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: textures[1] })
];


const meshes = [
  new THREE.InstancedMesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), materials[0], range * range),
  new THREE.InstancedMesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), materials[1], range * range)
];

// ADDING MESHES, WOULD BE GREAT IF SOMEONE COULD TELL ME IF THIS IS GOING TO WEAKEN PREFORMANCE WHEN IM ADDING MORE, SAY 100 x 100 
for (const mesh of meshes) {
  scene.add(mesh);
}

const waterDummy = new THREE.Mesh();
const stoneDummy = new THREE.Mesh();

for (let j = 0; j < range; j++) { // FOR LOOP CREATING A SQUARE OF BOXES
  for (let i = 0; i < range; i++) {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    
    if (i < (range / 2)) {
      console.log("water placed")
      waterDummy.position.x = i + 0.5;
      waterDummy.position.y = 1;
      waterDummy.position.z = j + 0.5;
      meshes[1].setMatrixAt(i + j * range, waterDummy.matrix); 
    } else {
      console.log("stone placed")
      stoneDummy.position.x = i + 0.5;
      stoneDummy.position.y = 2;
      stoneDummy.position.z = j + 0.5;
      meshes[0].setMatrixAt(i + j * range, stoneDummy.matrix); 
    }

    waterDummy.updateMatrix();
    stoneDummy.updateMatrix();
  }
}
// UPDATING BUFFERS
meshes[0].geometry.setAttribute('instanceTextureIndex', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(range * range).fill(0), 1));
meshes[0].geometry.getAttribute('instanceTextureIndex').needsUpdate = true;

meshes[1].geometry.setAttribute('instanceTextureIndex', new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute(new Float32Array(range * range).fill(1), 1));
meshes[1].geometry.getAttribute('instanceTextureIndex').needsUpdate = true;

camera.position.z = 9;
camera.position.x = 50;
camera.position.y = 5;

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();

// JUST MOVEMENT AROUND THE SCENE

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.code == "KeyD") {
    camera.position.x += 1;
  }
  if (event.code == "KeyA") {
    camera.position.x -= 1;
  }
  if (event.code == "KeyS") {
    camera.position.z += 1;
  }
  if (event.code == "KeyW") {
    camera.position.z -= 1;
  }
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried all sorts of things the the FOR loop, but changing the values seems to do nothing. Very strange for someone like me who is new to THREE JS and Javascript in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
    if (i < (range / 2)) {
      console.log("water placed")
      waterDummy.position.x = i + 0.5;
      waterDummy.position.y = 1;
      waterDummy.position.z = j + 0.5;
      meshes[1].setMatrixAt(i + j * range, waterDummy.matrix); 
    } else {
      console.log("stone placed")
      stoneDummy.position.x = i + 0.5;
      stoneDummy.position.y = 2;
      stoneDummy.position.z = j + 0.5;
      meshes[0].setMatrixAt(i + j * range, stoneDummy.matrix); 
    }

    waterDummy.updateMatrix();
    stoneDummy.updateMatrix();
```

into this:

```
    if (i < (range / 2)) {
      console.log("water placed")
      waterDummy.position.x = i + 0.5;
      waterDummy.position.y = 1;
      waterDummy.position.z = j + 0.5;
      waterDummy.updateMatrix();
      meshes[1].setMatrixAt(i + j * range, waterDummy.matrix); 
    } else {
      console.log("stone placed")
      stoneDummy.position.x = i + 0.5;
      stoneDummy.position.y = 2;
      stoneDummy.position.z = j + 0.5;
      stoneDummy.updateMatrix();
      meshes[0].setMatrixAt(i + j * range, stoneDummy.matrix); 
    }
```

`.updateMatrix()` has to be called before `.setMatrixAt()`.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked! I still have the extra mesh though at 0,0,0 any idea on how to remove it? :]

Comment: @Tadz Looking at your for-loop, you use it for filling of two instanced meshes. Not sure, if this is a good thing to do it this way. For example, when i = 0, you set the matrix for the item with 0 for water, but at the same time, matrix for the item with 0 for stones exists and maybe it's set to default values (identity matrix).

Comment: I agree its not the best. I fill 2 instanced meshes because i wanted 2 different textures / blocks in the scene, do you know how to do this with 1 instanced mesh instead? Changing its texture based on its Y axis so that Water remains on level 1/0 while stone is on 2/3 ?

Comment: @Tadz Use a texture atlas + modified material, that able to process the texture atlas in shaders by some contitions.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Do you have any links to any documentation, articles or tutorials for texture atlas and modified materials in THREE JS? thank you again!

Comment: @Tadz Well, there are many topics about instancing, texture atlases and modified materials on the forum :) https://discourse.threejs.org/